# C++ - what's the best way to initialize a variable in one function/file and then use it in main()/another file?

Tags: c++, variables, declaration

In C++, let's say I need to assign something to a variable and I want to do it outside of main() so the code is clearer, but then I want to use that variable for some operations inside main() or another function. For example I have:

```
int main()
{
int a = 10;
int b = 20;
SomeFunction(a,b);
}
```

And I want to have something like this:

```
void Init()
{
int a = 10;
int b = 20;
}

int main()
{
SomeFunction(a,b);
}
```

But obviously the compiler would say a and b are undeclared in the scope of main(). I could always declare them as global variables but there probably is a better way to solve that problem and I read that global variables are not that great in the long run. I don't want to use classes. So what do you guys propose?

Comment: What you're getting at is indeed global variables

Comment: Global variables are not bad by default.

Comment: Why are you avoiding objects?

Comment: _"I want to do it outside of main() so the code is clearer"_ Nope

Comment: @CMate I'm avoiding them because I'm working on a project for my studies and I can only use a subset of C++ (without streams, classes and objects).

Comment: **−1** To sum up, you want to do something Bad™ that you know is Bad™, for whatever undisclosed reason, and you're trying to exclude any reasonable answers. ***Why are you asking at all when you have decided what answers should be?***

Comment: You can also use classes.

Comment: Most things in C++ are objects, so you're kind of stuffed.

Comment: "I don't want to use classes" - so why are you using C++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use structures:

```
struct data
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

data Init()
{
    data ret;
    ret.x = 2;
    ret.y = 5;
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    data v = Init();
    SomeFunction(v.x, v.y); //or change the function and pass there the structure
    return 0;
}
```

If you don't want to use even struct then you can pass the values to Init function by reference. But in my opinion the first version is better.

```
void Init(int &a, int &b)
{
    a = 5;
    b = 6;
}

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    Init(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OP didn't want to use classes, and structs are equivalent to classes. It might be what he/she wants though

Comment: @keyser no, that's not a class. Adamf is not modeling an object but aggregating some variables into one struct. That's just an aggregate, and has nothing to do with classes and OOP.

Comment: I have added another solution - passing the values by reference to Init function. But using struct in this example is much better.

Comment: @Manu343726: Yes, that is a class.

Comment: @Manu343726 Aggregates are also known as "aggregate classes". They're  still classes.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit ok C++ defines old C `struct` as a `class` with public visibility by default. What I mean is that `struct` is being used as a C struct, to group multiple data into one variable, not to model any class/object with an special semantic, responsibility, etc.

Comment: Well, as long as that type of struct is not considered an object or a class it's fine. In that case using structs for this is definitely a great idea, thanks @AdamF

Comment: **−1** Uses a class while the question explicitly asked for no use of classes. Also the advice is just silly, but that's another matter.

Comment: @Manu343726: I don't see the distinction.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `extern` keyword. It allows variables to be defined once and then used everywhere. You can use it like this:

```
// main.cpp

extern int a;
extern int b;
```

and in your other file do

```
// Other.cpp

int a = 10;
int b = 20;
```

You can declare these with `extern` as many times as you want, but you can only define them once.

You can read more about `extern` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/language_linkage).

Comment: It's a shame I can't accept 2 answers because yours is very helpful for me too. Regarding your example, does Other.cpp need to be compiled/linked before main.cpp or anything like that?

Comment: @Virritus As long as it is linked with main.cpp it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the circumstances, you might want to store the values of those variables in a file and read them from the disk when you need them. For example, you could have data_values.txt in which you have space separated integers: 324 26 435 ....

Then define a file reading function in another source file, say data_reader.cpp:

```
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>

std::vector<int> get_data(const std::string& file_name){
  // Initialize a file stream
  std::ifstream data_stream(file_name);

  // Initialize return
  std::vector<int> values;

  // Read space separated integers into temp and add them to the back of
  // the vector.
  for (int temp; data_stream >> temp; values.push_back(temp)) 
  {} // No loop body is necessary.

  return values;
}
```

In whatever file you want to use that function, put

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
// Function declaration
std::vector<int> get_data(const std::string& file_name);
// File where the data is stored
const std::string my_data_file {"data_values.txt"};

void my_function() {
... // do stuff here
std::vector<int> data_values = get_data(my_data_file);
... // process data
}
```

If you are avoiding classes from the C++ standard library as well, then you would probably want to use an int array for the return value, a char* or char array for your file name and scanf or some other C function for reading the file.